# display countdown to datetime and not string

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am programming a countdown from a date initialized in my controller.
I do not know how to implement this in twig if there is a function in symfony to do this.
do you have research leads?

this is my code :

```
 /**
* @var User
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User",inversedBy="platsPoste")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id",referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $userPoste;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();

    $this->dureeValide = (new \DateTime('now'))->modify('+1 days');
    $this->creeA = (new \DateTime('now'));

    $this->commentaires = new ArrayCollection();

    return $this->getUserPoste();
    // TODO: Implement __toString() method.
}

//it's my entity which takes the dateTime and adds one day, and i want to display a countdown and note a string of date
```

```html
<tr>
    <th class="center">date of validity of food</th>
    <td class="center">{% if food.durationValidity %}{{ food.durationValidity|date('d-M-y h:m') }}{% endif %}</td>
</tr>
```

it looks like that :

[image]

And I want a countdown and not a string of date

thanks

Comment: well your code is working as per design: `if food.durationValidity then food.durationValidity else date('d-M-y h:m')` So currently your string of the date is being displayed because the variable `food.durationValidity` is not defined or is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to implement a counter, maybe you should clarify? A counter of what type? How does `food.durationValidity` relate to the code before it?

Comment: yes I know that I just want to know who can be display a countdown instead of my string
like this : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_countdown

Comment: well what have you tried? How about [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp) which is a javascript issue

Comment: That is the answer to your problem. They are providing you with the solution.

Comment: I don't know how can be process do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counter added into your html. You will have to figure out how to incorporate it with **symfony** and **twig**.

All I did was [copy and paste the code from the same source](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp) we both referenced and set the counter to count down from a period of 1 day or 24 hours. You can run it to verify.

```html
    <tr>
        <th class="center">date of validity of food</th>
        <td class="center"><span id="demo"></span></td>
    </tr>
    
    
    <script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
    
      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();
    
      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = tomorrow - now;
    
      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
      // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
      + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
      // If the count down is finished, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timer)

```
new moment.duration(1000).timer({ start: true }, callback);
//Setting this attribute to true will cause the timer to start once instantiated.
new moment.duration(1000).timer({ loop: true }, callback);
//Setting this attribute to true will cause the timer to **loop/restart** once a duration is complete.
```

Basically it allows you to execute a callback function until the end of duration.

Hope it helps.